# EmEditorで特定の拡張子に対して毎回、確認メッセージなどがでないようにしたいです

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。

正規なテキスト形式のファイルでない場合に、EmEditorで開こうとすると
「指定したエンコードで変換できない文字が含まれています……」と、何でどうやって開くか毎度確認を取ってきます。
その拡張子を毎回開くので強制的に開くのが決まった作業のため、いちいち確認が出ないで普通のテキストファイルのように文字化けのまま開けるように確認メッセージなどがでないように変更できますでしょうか？
必要な情報は閲覧できるので１００％表示できなくても支障は無いためです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

特定のファイル拡張子が開く設定のプロパティを開き、[ファイル] ページで、[Null文字を含むファイルで警告] と [変換できない不正な文字で警告] オプションをクリアしておけば、このような警告メッセージは表示されなくなります。特定のファイル拡張子の場合だけ警告メッセージが表示されないようにするためには、特定のファイル拡張子だけが関連付けられている設定を作成しておくことが必要です。

[image: EmEditor 設定のプロパティ - ファイル]

Comment: お世話になっております。回答ありがとうございます。出来ました。ありがとうございます。